# UITextView didChange delegate doesn't called when emoji entered

Tags: ios, swift, textview, delegates, emoji

I have a uitextview and i am doing a control everytime user enters a character to the textview. I am using textViewDidChange to detect that. TextViewDidChange called everytime i enter a character but it's not called when i entered an emoji.

So far i tried these beside of textViewDidChange,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I tried detecting in shouldChangeTextIn method. This is working for character but not for emoji as well.

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textChanged(notification:)), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`

I tried detecting with observers. Result is the same. Not working for emoji.

Lastly, i tried changing content type of textView to Ascii Capable. This removed emoji keyboard completely.

I am waiting for your helps. Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue on Xcode 12.2

Comment: I am using 12.4 . I also publish a testflight version and it acts the same on devices.

Comment: My friend tried on Xcode 12.3 and its still not called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a property `lastKnownText = myTextView.text`
2. Set a periodic check with time interval (for example, 2 times in a second)
3. In the check routine, compare lastKnownText against myTextView.text
4. If they are not equal, you know that the text has changed
5. In the same check routine, re-assign `lastKnownText = myTextView.text`

Comment: Yes, I think it can be done with periodic observes but i am curious why its not called. Maybe there is something i miss or dont know.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    myTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)  
}

@objc func textChanged() {
    print(myTextfield.text)
}

//Console:
//Optional("it works")
```

Comment: UITextView doesn't have addTarget method or editingChanged

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about TextField.